# How to make the MATLAB for loop faster

Tags: matlab

I am working on a dataset with 3750 text files each containing 10240*2 data. The file names are "Data_F_Ind0001 to Data_F_Ind3750". I have written a code to read each column of every file one-by-one and performed empirical mode decomposition (EMD). The EMD produced four variables I1 to I4 and for each of these four some other function (petropy) is performed. The problem with the code is, it's very slow. Can anyone suggest how to make it fast? I appreciate your help. Thank you.
I have give the sample code for processing first 9 files out of 3750. I have used same for loop for remaining files.

```
clear all;
close all;
l =1;
for k = 1:9
filename = sprintf('Data_F_Ind000%d.txt',k);
% a(:,:,k) = load(filename);
data = load (filename);
x = data(:,1);
y = data (:,2);

    alldata = eemd(x,0.01,10);
    I1 = alldata (1,:);
    I2 = alldata (2,:);
    I3 = alldata (3,:);
    I4 = alldata (4,:);
    imf = {I1, I2, I3, I4};
    for j = 1:4
        m1(k,j)= petropy(imf{j},3,1,'order');
        j=j+1;
        l=l+1;
    end        
end
```

Comment: in your inner for loop, i am not sure why you are incrementing `j` and `l`. j will already run for values 1, 2, 3, 4. By incrementing it inside the loop you are basically wasting the operation. Also, you are not using the value of `l` anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't seem to preallocate memory for `m1(k,j)`. Add `m1 = zeros(3750,4)` in front of the for loop.
I'm assuming m1() is an array, if it's a stuct or something else, change it accordingly.

Edit:
E.g. like this:

```
clear all;
close all;
l =1;
m1 = zeros(3750,4);
for k = 1:9
    ....
```

It's an important topic when dealing with for loops iteratively generating data - i'd suggest reading [this article](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/preallocating-arrays.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot Imoes.

Answer (score 1):

These are the things that comes to my mind by looking at your code:

- Don't put columns of data in variables x and y. By doing this you are using twice the memory. In you function eemd simply use data(:,1) as input. The same thing applies to I1 to I4 but I guess it has less effect as they are small size variables.
- You can try textscan or fscanf instead of sprintf. This should also improve your code.

Comment: Thank you Laleh. This helped me in improving my code.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more optimised version of your code:

```
m1 = zeros(3750, 4);
for k = 1:9
    filename = sprintf('Data_F_Ind000%d.txt',k);
    data = load(filename);
    alldata = eemd(data(:, 1),0.01,10);
%     for j = 1:4
%         m1(k,j)= petropy(alldata(j, :), 3, 1, 'order');
%     end
    m1(k, :) = arrayfun(@(j) petropy(alldata(j, :), 3, 1, 'order'), 1:4);
end
```

I have replaced the inner for loop with arrayfun. In case you don't understand it, you could use the for loop that i have commented out

Comment: Isn't `arrayfun()` usually (always?) slower than a for loop? But the other optimisations are neat, also easier to read.

Comment: Thank you ammportal for optimised code. I will try the same. Thanks Imoes for the additional information.

Comment: @lmoes yes, i think in this case `arrayfun` will be slower. It does speed up for very large number of iterations

Comment: @Dattaprasad I changed a bit of my code. The initialisation of m1 should be done outside the outer loop otherwise it will be reset in every iteration of `k`